# How to call a method in the Mainactivity by clicking a widget using Android studio?

Tags: java, android, methods, widget

I am a beginer, so be kind. I have an app with four buttons. If I run the app and click a single button, data is sent to specific device (one of four) using Bluetooth. I also have a widget that needs to call a method for data sending for the first device, so simulating a click of the first button i.e. calling a method in the Mainactivity class with a parameter 1.

Thank you for your help.

So currently from a widget I can start the Mainactivity, opening an app, but I would like to run a specific method instead.

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
    for (int i = 0; i < appWidgetIds.length; i++) {
        int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.io_t3widget);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.appwidget_text, pendingIntent);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }    
}
```

Comment: "...I would like to run a specific method instead." – You can't do that directly with a `PendingIntent`. What you can do, though, is put an extra on the `Intent` that you can check for in `MainActivity`, and decide what to do depending on its value, or even just if it's there or not.

Comment: Dear Mike, thanks, but I am a newbie and a would be grateful for a "few lines of code" or a link to more instructions.

Comment: Sorry, I missed your reply earlier. I'm not sure which parts you're unfamiliar with. You've got the basic setup there already. Adding an extra is easy – e.g., right after the `Intent intent = new ...` line, add `intent.putExtra("method_argument", 1);`. (That key `String` can be whatever you want, btw.) Then, in the `Activity`, `if (getIntent().hasExtra("method_argument")) { int arg = getIntent().getIntExtra("method_argument", 0); yourMethod(arg); }`.

Comment: Really grateful. It's working. I put that code in the OnResume() in the Mainactivity. Thanks.